# How to change the default browser using C#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I am trying to make a C# Console-Application that simply switches the default browser to Google Chrome (registry `UrlAssociations\\http\\UserChoice`). The code below somewhat works, as it *does* change the `Progid` value in the Windows registry, but .html files and links still open in the previous default browser, and nothing seems to "update". I have tried running my built .exe file as administrator which doesn't change anything. In the Windows Settings > Default Apps > Web browser it is set to Microsoft Edge every time I run my software - the `ProgId` in the Registry also gets changed back to the Microsoft Edge ID (`AppXq0fevzme2pys62n3e0fbqa7peapykr8v`).

```
RegistryKey regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\shell\\Associations\\UrlAssociations\\http\\UserChoice", true);
string browser = regkey.GetValue("Progid").ToString();

Console.WriteLine("Current browser: " + browser);
if (browser != "ChromeHTML") {
    regkey.SetValue("Progid", "ChromeHTML");
    string browser2 = regkey.GetValue("Progid").ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Changed " + browser + " to " + browser2);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Default browser is already Chrome");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

The code I use is found multiple places online, but is it missing something?
*(I'm using the Microsoft Surface Pro 3, if that changes anything)*

**Edit**

To clarify I am not trying to dictate what users' browser should be. I'm making this as our school resets our school-laptops' default browser to Internet Explorer each time you restart the computer - and there's no other way around it.

Comment: AFAIK you'll need to update another separate entry for each file extension you want to set the default application for. Maybe have a look at the answer of the following superuser question: https://superuser.com/questions/436939/where-is-the-default-program-associations-stored-in-the-registry

Comment: *Don't* try random things you find by googling, unless you understand what they do. The default browser is *NOT* the application associated with the  `.html` or `.htm` file extensions. You could change the association to Notepad if you want, by selecting `Open With` and clicking on `Always Open`. Those are completely different concepts. The brand of your laptop doesn't make any difference obviously. BTW you don't need to write a program to modify the registry. Just save the key you want as a .reg file. Double-clicking on it will update the registry with those values

Comment: BTW modifying the **user's** choice of a browser is a very, VERY bad and extremely intrusive idea. Unless you are the user's boss, you have no right to change this setting. If you are, you don't need to write a program. Just add a System Policy to set the appropriate registry settings to all computers in a domain, or a specific subset

Comment: why are you changing the browser to chrome?  do you work for google or get revenue for pushing their product?  But seriously ask people before changing settings, particularly something contentious such as choice of browser.

Comment: I know I shouldn't use random code - I like to think I understood what I tried. I am making this little program *for* my friends on their request. Our school-laptops are on the school-domain, and they set the default browser to Internet Explorer **each time** you restart the computer, it's driving people mad @Rob, so I'm simply trying to make them some software that automatically sets the default browser to 'Chrome' on startup! :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not changing the application associated with the `.html` extension doesn't change the fact that the Default Browser setting isn't changed in the Windows Settings.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos by that same logic, MS are doing something the exact same "very, VERY bad and extremely intrusive" thing by giving you a default browser. I work in a company that has 10k users and 80% use Chrome. Should I deliver new computers with IE as the default browser? Or should I set the default browser *once* to Chrome to simplify the life of 80% of my users? The remaining 20% can still manually change it back to whatever they want, it's just a *default setting*. In contrast, if GPO is used, they will not be able to change it to the browser of their choice.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You don't know much about GPO do you? If you set something in GPO, it's enforced. It's not "this is the default setting, but you can change it if you want to", it instead becomes "this is *company policy* and **must** be enforced". Don't tell me I misunderstood the discussion when the question is very simple: "How to change the default browser using C#". Nowhere in either the title or the question does the OP say whether he is (or is not) a: user, a system admin, application owner or anything in between. You made (and continue to make) quite a few assumptions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And being *some random application's author* does not stop you from being a user, a company owner, a system administrator, or even a (genuine) application owner. Hell, he doesn't even say how many users he wants to push this setting to! Clearly he knows it's a per-user setting since he's messing around the HKCU. So what makes you think that he would run it for anything other than *his own profile*? *Wrong registry setting, wrong mechanism, wrong credentials* - maybe he asked **because** it's wrong? So that someone could tell him the right way instead of saying it's wrong?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you still don't get it: where on the question does it say that he is in a position to use GPO? I've got 50 machines in front of me that will *never* be domain joined and they need to be configured with Chrome as the default browser. How does your link help now?

Comment: *As for where he intends to run it* he put that as a **comment** *after* you accused him of modifying user's choice. When you wrote that, you assumed stuff. And continue to do so. He asked how to do it programmatically. The point of this site is not to ask why, assume or discourage people from what *might* just be a very good reason. If you need more info, you ask, but don't assume reasons **nor** assume that *your way* is the right now.

Comment: **The OP explained what he actually wanted to do afte I had already abandoned that question** -- exactly my point. When you posted, you were assuming stuff. Like you're **assuming** now that GPO is *the one and only right tool for the job*. Interesting that MS created implemented into DISM the ability to export/import file associations... or that during profile creation they actually create a lot of their own file associations on the spot. Too bad you weren't around to tell them GPO was the one and only way of doing things, would have saved them some trouble...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos *9 months later you come to what, ask a similar question?* Nah, it's just that seeing nonsensical comments that assume the world is flat just tick me the wrong way sometimes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos His question is actually very well formulated. He says what he wants: *How to change the default browser using C#*, he shows what he tried - including code -, he says how far he's got with it and what the current problems still are. What else do you want? You either know how to answer the question or you don't but this is a prime example of a question that belongs in SO (he wants to do it in C#, says so on the title) and the format of the question is far better than that of 90% of questions here.